# does my code is right with the python or are there other way to initiate it with your perception?

Tags: python

```
#initialize the lists
stud_name_list =[] # list of names
    math_score_list = [] #scores in math
    science_score_list = [] #scores in science
    english_score_list = [] #scores in english
    computer_score_list = [] #scores in computer
    
    
    
    
    
    #this function will use the value returned by total_score, averages the value and add the result to the list
    def ave(score):
        average_s = score / 4
        average_score_list.append(average_s)
        
    #function to add names 
    def get_name(num):
        print("Student {:1}".format(num))
        name = input("Name of student: ")
        stud_name_list.append(name)
        
    #function to add all the scores
    def get_scores():
        x = 0
        y = 1
        #input loop 1
        while x < y:
            math_score = int(input("Score in Math:"))
            #checking the scores
            status = math_score
            if status == 1:
                 math_score_list.append(math_score)
                 x += 1
            else:
                print ("Incorrect score, score should be 0 or 100 or between 0 and 100")
                
    #add the score in science
        x = 0
        y = 1
        #input loop 2
        while x < y:
            science_score = int(input("Score in Science:"))
            #checking the scores
            status = check_score(science_score)
            if status == 1:
                 science_score_list.append(science_score)
                 x += 1
            else:
                print ("Incorrect score, score should be 0 or 100 or between 0 and 100")
                
    #f add the score in english
        x = 0
        y = 1
        #input loop 3
        while x < y:
            english_score = int(input("Score in English:"))`enter code here`
            #checking the scores
            status = check_score(english_score)
            if status == 1:
                 english_score_list.append(english_score)
                 x += 1
            else:
                print ("Incorrect score, score should be 0 or 100 or between 0 and 100")
                
    #add the score in computer
        x = 0
        y = 1
        #input loop 4
        while x < y:
            computer_score = int(input("Score in Computer:"))
            #checking the scores
            status = check_score(computer_score)
            if status == 1:
                 computer_score_list.append(computer_score)
                 x += 1
            else:
                print ("Incorrect score, score should be 0 or 100 or between 0 and 100")
    #get the total 
        total_s = total_score(math_score,science_score,english_score,computer_score)
        
    #use the above variable to get the average
        ave(total_s)
        
        
                
    #function to get the student data
    def get_stud_data(n_of_stud):
        i = 1
        #loop to enter and store the inputs
        while i <= n_of_stud:
            get_name(i)
            get_scores()
            
            
    #function to display the student data
    def display():
        i = 0
        l_size = n - 1
        print()
        
        print()
        #records output
        print()
        print("{:<10}".format("Class Record"))
        print()
        print("{:<10}".format("Student"),end=" ")
        print("{:<10}".format("Math"),end=" ")
        print("{:<10}".format("Science"),end=" ")
        print("{:<10}".format("English"),end=" ")
        print("{:<10}".format("Computer"),end=" ")
        print("{:<10}".format("Total"),end=" ")
        print("{:<10}".format("Average"))
        while i <= l_size:
            print ("{:<10}".format(stud_name_list[i]),end=" ")
            print ("{:<10}".format(math_score_list[i]),end=" ")
            print ("{:<10}".format(science_score_list[i]),end=" ")
           
        i = 0
        #histogram output
        print()
        print("{:<10}".format("Histogram"))
        while i <= l_size:
            histograms = average_score_list[i]/5
            histograms = int(histograms) #converting the variable  to int since float doesn't work in range
            print ("{:<10}".format(stud_name_list[i]),end=" ")
            for a in range(histograms):
                print("#",end="")
            print()
            i += 1
              
    #getting the number of students
    n = int(input("The number of students: "))
    #call the function to get the student data
    get_stud_data(n)
    #display the data
    display()
```

-Lists are one of the four built-in data structures in Python, together with tuples, dictionaries, and sets.

- Use any of the Python data structures to represent the data shown in the sample outputs below. Use
  nested looping to display the same.
  How to display() this right code of function? How to rewrite the code in the shortest way? What is the best thing to do in writing code?

Comment: See [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for details on what the method does.

Answer (score 0):

it works as string formating method it puts your wanted value in place of {} in string.

Answer (score 0):

String formatting can be accomplished in a variety of ways in Python, [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) being one of the ways. String formatting enables you to dynamically inject, evaluate and/or format data in a string, greatly simplifying the way you construct strings vs. alternative approaches like string concatenation.

There are several ways that string formatting can be accomplished in Python:

1. **New in Python 3.6** [Formatted String Literals aka f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html?highlight=string%20interpolation#formatted-string-literals)
2. [String `format()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html?highlight=string%20interpolation#the-string-format-method)
3. [Old-style string formatting using the `%` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html?highlight=string%20interpolation#old-string-formatting)

It is generally preferred to use approach (1) when possible. If not, the second most recommended is approach (2). Approach (3) is generally no longer recommended as a best practice for string formatting.